# Populate columns from another sheet if condition met - Dynamically

Tags: excel

How can I  populate a few columns from another sheet if condition met. For example:

Sheet 1 - Has 3 columns - Defect id, status, description

Sheet 2 - Will have 4 columns - Defect id, status, description and Analysis

Now condition part is - a) Sheet 2 should have only those columns where status is complete .
 b) For each row I will write analysis(4th column) .

Till here problem seems simple and I am able to achieve if I have to do this only once.

Tricky part is—Sheet 1 can change any time and rows can come in any order. Basically I am using RERESH function (I am taking these rows from another excel sheet).

My problem is first 3 columns of sheet 2 are fine as those are getting populated from vlookup or IF functions but what about 4th column (Analysis)? As this columns I am writing. Next day when I do refresh all in sheet 1, shuffling happening . As Analysis column is static.

Comment: Very good question indeed, unfortunately I don't know  an optimal solution. Directions you may consider: write a macro which checks for new rows and inserts / adds them in your second sheet; move your data into MS Access where you can easily create forms behaving exactly as you want.

Comment: Why create a second sheet with the exact same info just to filter it by completion status?  Just use the first sheet, add an `Analysis` column, and apply a filter on `Status` when you only want to see completed ones.